# Autocorrelation strange results?

Tags: python, autocorrelation

I'm trying to do autocorrelation with numpy in python but i'm getting strange results :

For a **simple 440Hz** sine wave sample :
[image]

This is the result of autocorrelation :
[image]

Is this normal ? Maybe I'm not understanding everything

UPDATE :

Here is my code :

```
def autocorrelation(signal):
  res = np.correlate(signal, signal, mode='same')
  res = res[len(res)//2:]
  plt.plot(signal)
  plt.show()
  plt.plot(res)

  plt.show()
```

Comment: No it's not normal for a pure sine wave.

Comment: @Fat32 Do you have any idea / explanation ? I noticed that when I apply a window to the signal the correlation works well...

Comment: you don't have to apply a window. I cannot comment on numpy as I have only checked for xcorr of matlab. Whatever function you may use you should not get this **noise** as the output of an autocorrelator. Also note that signal of length 500 producing autocorrelation of length 250 is not usual either. you are doing something wrong. put your code for better responses.

Comment: Ok thank you. I updated my post. The lenght is normal as I'm retrieving the half of the correlation function, but I don't know why I'm getting this weird result

Comment: Your code works for me when I call it with `signal=np.sin(2*np.pi*440*np.arange(0,4.0/f, 1.0/16000))` i.e. a 440Hz sine wave sampled at 16kHz and a duration of 4 cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have some overflow/underflow issues? At about 32768, there are signal glitches in the autocorrelation results. Could it be that your calculations are done on 16 bits?

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you very much! My code reading the wave file was : `data = np.fromstring(wav.readframes(-1), 'Int16')` so I updated it to `data = np.fromstring(wav.readframes(-1), 'Int16').astype('Int64')` and it worked like a charm ! However I'm wondering if it's the best solution...

Comment: you can typecast them to float before calling `np.correlate`.

Comment: i don't do `python` or `numpy` but doesn't it normally work on floating-point numbers?